# Cannot install Node modules

Tags: node.js, cordova, command-line, npm, ionic-framework

I am trying to install node modules but getting the following long list of errors.

[image: Error Screenshot]

I am using command like `npm install -g ionic` or `npm install -g cordova`.

What I have tried so far-

1. I have tried removing and reinstalling latest version of Node.js
2. I have tried installing 32 and 64 bit versions of Node.js
3. I have also tried setting the `--registry` parameter to `http://registry.npmjs.org/` and `https://registry.npmjs.org/`.
4. I have tried running command prompt and git bash shell as Administrator.

Notes:

- I am working on Windows 8.1 Pro 64 bit.
- I am not behind any firewall or proxy. All my internet work perfect.
- I have turned my windows firewall off as well.

Please help. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Yes I did. Point 4 in what I have tried so far.

Comment: Actually this is pretty much it. It just keeps on repeating.

Comment: What show in browser `http://registry.npmjs.org/` or `https://registry.npmjs.org/`?

Comment: Here is the screenshot of the result http://prntscr.com/80dbr7

Comment: Hmmm.. Try install at node 0.12.6 not 0.12.7.

Comment: While I am installing Nodejs 0.12.6, let me also tell that it downloads some files and folders of some 58 MB in the Temp folder when I try to install node module.

Comment: Did that. Still no change. Error keeps showing up every 2 seconds, though files and folders are being created at the same time.